# Setting timer in mysql/phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

so I have a question regarding timing the addition of a row in a mysql table in phpmyadmin. These are the tables in question:

```
/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Contribution                                          */
/*==============================================================*/
create table Contribution
(
   ContributionID       int not null auto_increment,
   CreatedByUserId      int not null,
   StoryID              int not null,
   PreviousCID          int,
   NextCID              int,
   OriginalCID          int,
   Content              longblob not null,
   CreatedDate          datetime not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   primary key (ContributionID)
);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: ContributionState                                     */
/*==============================================================*/
create table ContributionState
(
   ContributionStateID  int not null auto_increment,
   Title                national varchar(100) not null,
   DisplayOrder         int not null,
   primary key (ContributionStateID)
);

INSERT INTO ContributionState(ContributionStateID,Title,DisplayOrder) 
VALUES (1,N'Vote up',1),
(2,N'Vote Down',2),
(3,N'Vulgar',3),
(4,N'Spam',4),
(5,N'Accepted',5),
(6,N'Rejected',6),
(7,N'Live',7),
(8,N'Deleted',8);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Contribution_States                                   */
/*==============================================================*/
create table Contribution_States
(
   Contribution_StatesID int not null auto_increment,
   ContributionStateID  int not null,
   ContributionID       int not null,//derived from contribution table
   UserID               int not null,
   CreatedDate          datetime not null DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   primary key (Contribution_StatesID)
);
```

So, I have a php file to add a new contribution which adds a new row to the contribution table and accordingly adds a new row to the Contribution_States table. When added, they have a default ContributionStateID of 5 meaning they are accepted and users can start voting for/against them, but in order to be live(7) or rejected(6), users will vote during a certain allocated time after which they cannot vote. I want to give a certain time during which users can vote(5 minutes in this case for the sake of testing right now), but I don't know where to add it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a timestamp column 'voteExpires' set to the current timestamp plus 5 minutes. This could be done using an **on insert** trigger.

Comment: Just so that I understand you correctly, this timestamp would be added with the contribution table or in contribution_state table. Which would be more advisable? 

Also, how would I check if 5 minutes have passed? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Since, if I understand correctly, the Contribution records is the one that "expires", it would be in that table. The other table appears to be a lookup table to populate a drop-down or other UI element during voting. Do you have another table to record votes?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The purpose of the other table is to populate all instances of voting, contributions being added/rejected/deleted and so on. But I still have one question, how would I continually check if the currenttime is equal to the 'voteExpires' value to add a contributionState of rejected/live.

P.S.: live means that it was accepted

Comment: Why isn't there a foreign key between the two tables? Are you saying that multiple records in the 2nd table might have the same value for title?

Comment: You may have misunderstood me, the other table I was referring to is the Contribution_States table which holds all instances of adding a contribution/deleting/accepting/ voting/ and so on. There is a foreign key which is the ContributionID column. This is derived from ContributionID in the contribution table. If you can, please answer my second question. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.You could either use a timed event (AJAX) in the browser to find out the status with a query on the server side, or check it when a vote is saved. It should be trivial to write a SQL query that compares the `expired` column to the current timestamp. If it's less than the current timestamp (or one of the two states) then it's expired and voting stops. You can also get the time (seconds) between the timestamp and `expired` to show a countdown timer for voting. MySql has several functions for interval calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.